How to change Local Axis of bone
I am new to rigging, and was wondering what the best way to change the local axis of a bone is.
I have a character, and their main body bone is at an angle like in the picture. This is a problem for when I animate because I will need to be animating multiple curves to go straight up or to the side. I would like for the Z to be straight up, and the x and y to be to their respective sides.
The bone above this is perfectly vertical so I can't change the position of the tail otherwise I will mess up the bone above.
What is the correct way to address this issue? Add another bone? Or can I change the axis for this body bone.
Thanks

if you want the small bone to be vertical, and don't want to move the big bone above, and don't want the 2 bones to be disconnected, you need to move its head until it's aligned with the tail

The problem is, I need the head to be in the center of the model where it currently is so that the legs don't move when I rotate the body.
Is it a problem if I disconnect them? Like is that a rigging no-no?
I suppose I could have the big bone above not be perfectly up and down since it will just be rotated only. I was just curious if there was another way to achieve both bones having true local axis. I could also through in a dummy bone I suppose that I just don't use.

I'm not sure to understand but if you want to disconnect press Alt P > Disconnect Bone?
